# Is there a way to "shrink" this tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-cd

I used a graphical editor to construct a some tikzcd diagrams, but I am looking for a way to "shrink" the diagram if possible, as they are quite wide, and aren't quite fitting on my pages. Any help would be much appreciated.

A sample of one such diagram is as follows:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

  \[ \begin{tikzcd}
{k[x,y,t]/(ab-c,d-e)} &  &  &  &  &  \\
& {k[x,y,t]/(ab-c,d-e) \otimes_{k[t]} k[t]/(d-e)} \arrow[lu, "\sigma", dotted] &  &  &  &  \\
&  &  & {k[x,y,t]/(ab-c,d-e)} \arrow[llu, "\theta", dotted] &  & {k[x,y,t]} \arrow[ll, "\varphi"] \arrow[llllu, "\psi", bend right] \arrow[llllluu, "g", bend right] \\
&  &  &  &  &  \\
&  &  & 0 \arrow[uu, "\epsilon"] \arrow[llluuuu, "h", bend left] \arrow[lluuu, "\zeta", bend left] &  & {(ab-c,d-e)} \arrow[uu, "\iota"] \arrow[ll, "\rho"', no head] \end{tikzcd} \]
```

Comment: You could shrink it by saying e.g. `\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=5pt,column sep=2pt] ...`. The question is what you really want to achieve in the end. Maybe a matrix is here not the optimal thing to do?

Answer (score 4):

i would:

- reduce distance between columns (`column sep=small`)
- reduce number of columns and rows
- rewrite math expression with use of `\frac`

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small]
\frac{k[x,y,t]}{(ab-c,d-e)}
    &   &   &                                           \\
    & \frac{k[x,y,t]}{(ab-c,d-e)} \otimes_{k[t]} \frac{k[t]}{(d-e)}
        \ar[lu,"\sigma",dotted]
        &   &                                           \\
    &   & \frac{k[x,y,t]}{(ab-c,d-e)} \ar[lu, "\theta", dotted]
            & k[x,y,t] \ar[l, "\varphi"]
                       \ar[llu, "\psi", bend right=45]
                       \ar[llluu, "g",  bend right=45]  \\
    &   & 0 \ar[u, "\epsilon"]
            \ar[luu, "\zeta", bend left]
            \ar[lluuu, "h", bend left]
             &  (ab-c,d-e) \ar[u, "\iota"]
                           \ar[l, "\rho"', no head]
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you sure these are fractions? (I never divided by something like `(ab-c,d-e)`...)

Comment: @marmot, i'm not sure.  i don't know context of diagram, not what some expression in it means, but op use symbol `/` , which us usually in math means fraction.  it can explain use of fraction for shorter writing for `/`. i'll think about it tomorrow, now it's time to sleep ...

Comment: They are quotients in ring theory. I have seen people write  them as fractions, but mathematically they aren't the same as fractions.

Comment: @AGApprentice, this can be explained in (for example) image caption or some other place in text (that fractions used are not "standard" fractions ... (ring theory is not in my focus of interest ;-))

Answer (score 1):

With a bit of cheating you can transform your diagram to

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[ \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=2em,column sep=1em]
{k[x,y,t]/(ab-c,d-e)} &  &  &  &  &  \\
& \makebox[1em][c]{$k[x,y,t]/(ab-c,d-e) \otimes_{k[t]} k[t]/(d-e)$} \arrow[lu, "\sigma", dotted] &  &  &  &  \\
&  &  & {k[x,y,t]/(ab-c,d-e)} \arrow[llu, "\theta", dotted] &  & {k[x,y,t]} \arrow[ll, "\varphi"] \arrow[llllu, "\psi", bend right] \arrow[llllluu, "g", bend right] \\
&  &  &  &  &  \\
&  &  & 0 \arrow[uu, "\epsilon"] \arrow[llluuuu, "h",
out=180,in=-120,looseness=1.5,overlay] \arrow[lluuu, "\zeta", bend left] &  & {(ab-c,d-e)} \arrow[uu, "\iota"] \arrow[ll, "\rho"', no head] 
\end{tikzcd} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `cramped` key is a convenient way to remove some of the whitespace while retaining the structure of the diagram.

But I think you are going to be up against the fact that a page is longer than it is wide. Is there a particular reason the flow of the diagram has to be diagonal across the page? I would suggest a re-orientation:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
 % \begin{tikzcd}[cramped] % Remove some of the whitespace
&&&
{(ab-c,d-e)} \arrow[ld, "\rho"', no head]   \arrow[rd,  "\iota"]&&&\\
&&
0 \arrow[rd, "\epsilon"]  \arrow[dddr, "\zeta", end anchor={[xshift=-1.5cm, yshift=0.3cm]}, bend right=15]
\arrow[dddddr,swap, "h", end anchor={[xshift=0cm, yshift=0.2cm]}, bend right=60]
&&
{k[x,y,t]} \arrow[dl, "\varphi"]    \arrow[dddl, "\psi", end anchor={[xshift=1.5cm, yshift=0.3cm]}, bend left=10] 
\arrow[dddddl, "g", end anchor={[xshift=0.8cm, yshift=-0.1cm]}, bend left=40]&&\\
&&& {k[x,y,t]/(ab-c,d-e)}  \arrow[dd, "\theta", dotted] &&&\\
&&&&&&\\
&&& \makebox[1em][c]{$k[x,y,t]/(ab-c,d-e) \otimes_{k[t]} k[t]/(d-e)$}  \arrow[dd, "\sigma", dotted] &&&\\
&&&&&&\\
&&& {k[x,y,t]/(ab-c,d-e)} &&&\\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

(I also wonder why the entire diagram is in a displayed math environment).

Output:
[image]

Comment: It doesn't need to be diagonal across the page. There's no set style for these things.  That's just what I'm used to. Thanks, this works. I just need to learn tikz/tikzcd instead of messing around with graphical tools and stuff. But I struggle with the manuals for some reason.

Comment: Experience is definitely the key with tikz. If you have to do these diagrams often, I wouldn't worry about it as you will quickly gain proficiency and develop a consistent way of laying them out.